# How to run node in webhosting?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'am creating 2d mmorpg game and I upload client and socket.io server on webhosting, but don't know how to start server.js, if i'am right then I have to run node with package.json but I don't know how to run it in webhosting...

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Example server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "author": "Aurelijus",
  "private": true,
  "license": "BSD",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.13.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

server example:

```
var http = require("http").createServer(), io = require("socket.io").listen(http);

http.listen(8080);


//================================  Connection stuff ================================//
io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket)
{
    socket.on('player connected', function(data)
    {   
    };
});
console.log('Server listening on port %s', http.address().port);
```

Thanks, I hope it's not out of topic :\

Comment: You need to add a few more details for us to be able to help.  What kind of server are you putting this on?  Are you just uploading to a web hosting service?  you need to have access to the console on the server to run node apps, otherwise you can use a service like Heroku

Comment: my hosting says that they support node I'am putting this on simple webhosting, wait i'am going to upload server.js

Comment: Can you ssh into the web server?  You start node on the server the same as you start it on your local machine.  First run ```npm install``` then run ```npm start``` on the server

Comment: @PeterGrainger please post your answer I will mark it as an answer

Comment: OK, did that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To start a node on a webserver it is the same as locally.

```
npm install
npm start
```